# CSS Fluid Video

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive video component for my portfolio site.

It's essentially a mobile app video which I am positioning on top of a phone mockup, however, my problem is that I want to mask/crop them both within a container, but still make them responsive or fluid.

I've figured that using ***Overflow hidden*** on the containing div works but when I change the browser size I would like the height of the containing div to maintain the masking.

Here are some images to describe my situation.

and also a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Djsquid/bqoh7gs6/)

```
<section class="feed">
    <div class="feed-element">
        <div class="animation">
            <div class="screen">
                <div class='embed-container'>
                    <iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/281167304?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0"' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <img src="http://www.anthonyeamens.co.uk/test/images/iphone@2x.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feed-text">
        <h1>
      Title
      </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image: Desktop Version]

[image: Mobile Version]

Comment: Is it a problem for you crop directly the phone's img? Do you want to see that "alpha overflow effect" or is it just an example to let us know how much phone you want to see?

Comment: Yeah the alpha overflow in the image is just to show how much of the phone I wanted visible in the container div

Comment: Ok, then maybe it is more simple for you crop directly that image. if I had to do the work, I would start with an already correct image without thinking about how to make very complicated masks to show only a part of it. But this is only my opinion. ;)

Comment: I get your point and appreciate your reply :) I wish I could crop the image, however by cropping the image I would then need to crop the video which is going on top of the phone, and I would have too many videos to rework by doing this. I assumed just masking them would be easy enough but wanting them responsive also is proving very difficult.

Comment: Why redo your videos? https://jsfiddle.net/bqoh7gs6/8/ Is this what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'll be re-using this component throughout my portfolio site on different projects, and I want to be able to crop the phone and video and only show portions of it. I appreciate the attempt though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will try with this solution. First of all, **this is not a good solution**: it is plenty of MAGIC NUMBERS (https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/), a really bad thing in CSS.

Iframe & Phone image have no related measures (the first one is almost a square, the last one is pretty vertical) so it's really hard to make them get along.

For all these reasons, my first answer is: *ok, here there is a structural problem and all the work should be redesigned to remove all those hack&trick*.

However, I know, this isn't a real solution for you 'cause you have to finish your work with the videos & images you have already done. So, to try to help you I kept the structure you have created with very very small changes: I trasformed phone image in a background and I removed some div's. 
This is the situation.

**CSS:**

```
.feed {
  max-width:1170px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2.564102564102564%; /* how scary! (^_^;)  */
  grid-column: span 12;
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 50px 0px;
}

.feed-element {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;

  background-image:url("http://www.anthonyeamens.co.uk/test/images/iphone@2x.png");
  background-size: auto 124%; /* MAGIC NUMBER */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: center -28%; /* MAGIC NUMBER */
}

.feed-text {
  grid-column: 7 / 13;
}

.animation {
  max-width: 370px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.embed-container { 
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 124%; /* MAGIC NUMBER */
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin-top: 22.84%;  /* MAGIC NUMBER  */
  margin-left:1px;     /* MAGIC NUMBER  */
} 

.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 8%; /* MAGIC NUMBER  */
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .feed-element {grid-column: span 12;}
  .feed-text {grid-column: span 12;}
}
```

And this is **HTML**:

```
<section class="feed">
  <div class="feed-element">
    <div class="animation">
        <div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/281167304?autoplay=1&loop=1&color=357ded&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0"' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="feed-text">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I don't know why but the Stackoverflow Code Snippet have some troubles working with these CSS & HTML - maybe because there is an iframe inside another iframe... or just because **this is not a good solution**... (^_^;), but I tried it in a normal situation with my browsers and it works.

I create also a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/692hd1tL/5/

So, you can use this solution, if you want, but after this work... **forgot it**! Absolutely! :D

Cheers :)

Comment: This is absolute perfection! exactly what I needed! You are a legend :) Thank you so much! I've learnt a lot from this exercise.

Comment: Ahahaha... a legend! You're exaggerated! ;) I taught you something terrible. Btw, I'm happy to have helped you, Anthony ;)

Comment: Hey ReSedano, quick question... do you know the best method for pausing video when out of the viewport? or if I had multiple videos down the page, I want to be able to play one when in viewport and pause the other when out of viewport?

Comment: Hi Anthony. I never had some problem so I don't know 'the best method', but I tell you what I would do. First of all, I'd use this jquery plugin https://github.com/xobotyi/viewport.jquery to detect if a video is in my viewport and then, using an if statemen on `$(".myVideo:in-viewport");` I'd use still jquery to play or pause that video.

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much ReSedano, you've been incredibly helpful :)